# How to get a list of values to a view from controller while applying concatenation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hi my query is I've to print list of names concatenated with a ',' till the last second name retrieved.
For e.g., 
**We wish John, Smith, Sally, Mike, Dean a very happy birthday!**
I managed to get the list of user names from the controller, but unable to print in the view.

Controller:

```
      objUser.Usernames = dbContext.EmployeeProfiles.Where(u => u.DOB == date1).Select(u => u.Name).ToList();
```

My View:

```
                @foreach (var item in Model.Usernames)
                {
                    string append = "We wish " + item + ", a very Happy Birthday!";
                    @append;
                }
```

Here it's repeating same message with each item in Model.Usernames.
Also I need to remove the last ','.

How can I achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.Join` to cleanly join together a list of strings into a single string.  Something as simple as this:

```
We wish @string.Join(", " Model.Usernames) a very Happy Birthday!
```

No need for a loop, for server-side string literals, etc.  Simply emit the joined string where you need it.